# Android 2.1, HTC Hero EU and WIFI configuration issues

Tags: wi-fi, 2.1-eclair, htc-hero

After many search and try, it seem to be impossible to connect to a WIFI network with hidden SSID. But perhaps I did my research wrong...

**So, is there any way to connect to a WIFI network with hidden SSID?**

An other problem: when I set an IP for a WIFI network without DHCP, that IP applies to all other configured networks, and when I move to an other network, I must change manually IP configuration each time!

**So, is there some kind of profile for each network like on the iPhone to bypass this problem?**

it is important for me to do that with the official HTC ROM: I do not want to use a hacked rom.

Thank you in advance for your help ^

**Some infos on the phone below:**

> **[HTC Hero EU](http://www.htc.com/europe/product/hero/specification.html)**
>
> ***Firmware***
>
> 2.1-update 1
>
> ***Baseband-Version***
>
> 63.18.55.06PU_6.35.15.11
>
> ***Kernel-Version***
>
> 2.6.29-063c4d24
>
> htc-kernel@and18-2 #1
>
> ***Buil-Nummer***
>
> 3.32.405.1 CL191507 release-keys
>
> ***Software-Nummer***
>
> 3.32.405.1
>
> ***Browser version***
>
> WebKit 3.1

Answer (score 2):

From what I've read this is more than just an [issue with the HTC Hero](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1041) and seemingly still hasn't been fixed completely(scroll to bottom of the page).  However I did find several suggestions:

1. [One of the comments](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1041#c231) claimed he "choose 'up to 54mbps' for hidden SSID on my netgear router" and it worked - maybe this will work for you.
2. I also read (and confirmed) that if you are using a router with b/g/n - you need to switch it to just b/g mode for it work with a HTC Hero.  I have not confirmed this with a hidden SSID (confirmed with a broadcasted SSID) but its a suggestion to try if you don't mind using only b/g mode. (I'm pretty sure this is the same as suggestion 1 but just in case he meant something else I provided this)
3. You could also try [HiddenSSID Enabler](https://market.android.com/details?id=jp.sourceforge.soopy.hidden.ssid.enabler&feature=search_result).  I have not tried this so I can't confirm but the comments on the app seem to indicate it works fine.

Hope one of these suggestions works for you.

Comment: Thanks for you response. What about IP profiles with Android?

Comment: @G. Qyy Sorry I'm not sure what you mean? Are you talking about setting specific IP configurations based on whatever network you are on?

Comment: Exactly. This is possible on the iPhone, but Android seems to apply IP configuration to all networks...