# Samsung Galaxy S problem :WiFi doesn't reconnect with SSID broadcast disabled

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, wi-fi

Hi
I have a problem with my Wifi connection.
My Samsung Galaxy S does not connect to my Linksys wrt54g router after I'm disabling the SSID broadcast.

The connection is automatically returned when I enable the SSID Broadcast.
Why is it like that and how can I fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2782/android-2-1-htc-hero-eu-and-wifi-configuration-issues/

Answer (score 2):

This is because Android by default (manufactures could of added something ) connect using only the SSID, not the BSSID.

See this issue : http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1041

This app here might help: https://market.android.com/details?id=jp.sourceforge.soopy.hidden.ssid.enabler&feature=search_result

This is the design to connect by SSID instead of BSSID for mesh networks, this becomes helpful.

Also if your router and phone support WPS button, try that.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling the SSID broadcast doesn't provide any meaningful security to your wireless network. The days that it might help make your network harder to spot are long, long past.

As such the best "fix" is to re-enable the SSID broadcast.

Comment: This is right, not displaying the SSID does not help at all, you still show up to every computer. WPA is the only working security for WiFi. (WPA-AES has better OS support)